# SQL Server 2008 - The report manager URL shows a page without Properties tab

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, reportserver, reportmanager

I have SQL Server 2008 Developer Edition and I'm facing the following issues with the Reporting Services.

1. When I open the Report Manager URL (I get it from the Reporting Services Configuration Manager) in a browser, it shows me a SQL Server Reporting Services page with a folder icon on top left and links with text 'Home', 'My subscriptions', 'Help' on top right. That's it, I don't get to see anything else. 
   I have a virtual directory with the same name as specified for Report Manager in Reporting Services Configuration Manager.
2. Opening the Report Server in the browser gives the following error message-

   *Reporting Services Error
       The report server cannot open a connection to the report server database. A connection to the database is required for all requests and processing. (rsReportServerDatabaseUnavailable) Get Online Help
       A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)*

I tried the following at the command prompt in order to resolve it-

```
rsconfig -c -s <SQLSERVERNAME> -d reportserver -a Windows -u <MYDOMAIN\MYACCOUNT> -p <PASSWORD>
```

but I got another error saying `Report Server WMI Provider error: Invalid namespace`

I would really appreciate any help on this.

cheers

Answer (score 2):

I was finally able to get through both  the problems by opening a port in Windows firewall for the Report Server.

For Windows 2003 and Vista the steps are mentioned here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934283.aspx

cheers

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Open Start -> SQL Server (20xx) -> find "Reporting Services Configuration Manager" in subfolders -> go to Database tab -> check if "sql server name" and "Database Name" are selected correctly. It is the database which reporting services stores reports in it.

**2)** if it was OK, check if you have more the one sql instances. If you have more than one instances on your machine, decide which one you want to use. for example sql server 2008 or sql server 2012. Maybe you are using the URL of the reporting services 2008 that is not using a correct database in its "Reporting Services Configuration Manager"